# Disabling bash history index in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

When I SSH into somewhere, I see something line this in the terminal:
[504]%

Looking it up, looks like its my bash shell history. How can I disable this index display and show the current working directory instead?

Answer (score -1):

On the target system (the one you SSH into), find out where the bash variable **PS1** is being set (`grep PS1= .bash*`), read `man bash`, the **PROMPTING** section, and set **PS1** the way you want to.